# Установка apk на android

Tags: android, apk

Как установить apk на android? Файл через приложение не открывается, вылетает. Как установить чтобы приложение не вылетало? Подробнее: если открыть файл .apk то приложение через которое открывается файл вылетает, а файл не открывается.

Comment: Подозреваю дело в установщике (если не в apk), попробуйте переустановить установщик apk (например через adb), либо установите другую прошивку на телефон.

Comment: С установщиком все ок, если я открою через мои файлы (встроенный файловый менеджер) то все ок, любой ЕС, то все ок а вот если мой файловый менеджер то он вылетает.

Answer (score 0):

adb install. 
ADB (Android Debug Bridge - Отладочный мост Android) - инструмент, который устанавливается вместе с Android-SDK и позволяет управлять устройством на базе ОС Android.
Работает на всех Android-устройствах, где данный функционал не был намеренно заблокирован производителем.
Здесь и далее: PC - ПК, компьютер к которому подключено устройство.
ADB - консольное приложение для PC, с помощью которого производится отладка Android устройств, в том числе и эмуляторов. 
Работает по принципу клиент-сервер. При первом запуске ADB с любой командой создается сервер в виде системной службы (демона), которая будет прослушивать все команды, посылаемые на порт 5037.
[FAQ](https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=383300)

Comment: Я имел ввиду установка через приложение, как через ES проводник например

Comment: Вы можете установить apk через эмулятор терминала Android на самом устройстве. 

```~Android$ su

~Android# cd sdcard

~Android# ls

~Android# pm install app.apk
```
https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1793141

Comment: Еще подробнее: это должен быть файловый менеджер который может открывать apk через установщик пакетов

Comment: тогда: 1) удостовериться, что .apk  корректный, 2) Испробовать все доступные файловые менеджеры

Comment: С apk все ок, если я открою через мои файлы (встроенный файловый менеджер) то все ок, любой ЕС, то все ок а вот если мой файловый менеджер то он вылетает.

Comment: "мой файловый менеджер" - самописный? Убедитесь, что приложение запрашивает ( и получает) все нужные разрешения

Comment: Ему кроме WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE и READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE что-то надо?

Comment: android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES

Comment: Нет, проблему решило частично, теперь он не вылетает, но при попытке уствновить, приложение установщика пишет что синтетическая ошибка, файл нормальный, или же установщик вылетает.

Comment: Возьмите в привычку прикладывать логи ошибок к вопросам. Без логов ошибки решение проблемы превращается в гадание на кофейной гуще. 
Возможно, установщик пытается отобразить ход установки, но ему негде)